# What does "I won't never" mean in this phrase?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

- I won't never regret these scars from trying to hold on to you.

I came across some poetry from [*America's Got Talent*](https://youtu.be/tdjIFkM-ohQ) and was confused about what "I won't never" is actually intended to mean.

Is there really such a thing in English language as double negation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In certain case, double negation doesn't cancel the negation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218473/in-certain-case-double-negation-doesnt-cancel-the-negation)

Comment: Thanks. So based on the answer from the link you provide, from my understanding, it means I will regret these scars? I'm sorry English is not my first language.

Comment: @Woppi: read the answer, not the question. It means *I will never regret these scars*.

Comment: Poetry doesn't have to be right to be good. You could read the sentence as "I won't regret these scars. Never!"

Comment: @PeterShor Of course I read the answer on that page: Wife: Did you go to that strip club last night? Husband: Let's put it this way: I didn't not go. (He went to the strip club.) but I want to clarify my understanding of that answer. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Woppi: The answer also contains the example "I can't get no satisfaction," which means "I can't get any satisfaction." To a native English speaker, it's obvious which of these two categories "I won't never regret" belongs to, but I guess it's not to a English learner.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

It means "Will never" or "Won't ever" regret these scars. It's not very good English. Very informal. Some people do speak like that. Maybe you could say less educated people speak like that.

Answer (score 1):

It should be "will never" or "won't ever". The English used in poetry and songs is not always correct.

Comment: It's not specifically poetry/songs, this is a common dialect.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I didn't know it was common dialect, it's my first time hearing "I won't never".

Comment: It's like "I ain't got no".